# Don't display if attribute is string(0)

Tags: php, string, magento, null

I'm using the following section of code to display some icons on our Magento store with the idea being if there is nothing added in the icons section it shouldn't display, for some reason this isn't working...it is displaying a division as if something is there but there is actually nothing.

```
<?php 
if($_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->geticons()), 'icons') !== null): 
?>
    <div class="product-icons">
        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->geticons()), 'icons') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It needs to show Icons if they are coded in the attribute field and then hide the division if there is nothing added.

I've worked out that the code is returning a value of `string(0)` what do I need to change in my coding to get the desired effect?

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean?

Comment: Are you sure the productAttribute returns null when there's no icons? And not something like false or 0?

Comment: @Alexander Varwijk - Not 100% sure of what it is returning when there isn't anything actually, is there an easy way to check? When you look at the page after it has been loaded there is nothing there in the div tags so assumed it was a value of null

Comment: @Vince Pettit try adding an `echo var_dump($_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->geticons()), 'icons'));` it could just be an empty string in case of which `!== null` won't catch it.

Comment: looks like it's returning string(0)

Comment: What do I need to change `!== null` to in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the thing you need, and you don't need call the same functionality twice to get the empty result. Define your variable and check if it is empty (null, undefined or false) or not

```
<?php $icons = $_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->getIcons()), 'icons');?>
<?php if(!empty($icons)):?>
    <div class="product-icons">
        <?php echo $icons;?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

this could be even better solution as it wont call the helper unless there are icons defined but you first have to try it out on your codebase.

```
<?php if($_product->getIcons()):?>
    <div class="product-icons">
        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->getIcons()), 'icons') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and please check if it isn't a typo and it really is:

```
$_product->geticons()
```

or should it be

```
$_product->getIcons()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<?php
if($_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->geticons()), 'icons'))
{
     echo "<div class=\"product-icons\">";
     echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->geticons()), 'icons');
     echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

would be better!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
  if(!empty($_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->geticons()), 'icons')))
    {
      echo "<div class=\"product-icons\">";
      echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,($_product->geticons()), 'icons');
      echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: or try isset() instead of !empty()